# Swift Facebook Login sdk error with code 2

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am getting an error while logging in with Facebook. And **it was working** about 3-4 months ago.

Now I am back at developing this app again and I changed the development target to iOS 13.0 from iOS 12.0 and add the SceneDelegate and other necessary things. Actually, I don't think this is the reason but good to mention.

Now I am getting this error:

> FBSDKLog: Cannot login without a valid login configuration. Please
> make sure the `LoginConfiguration` provided is non-nil Error
> Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=2 "(null)"
> UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Cannot login
> without a valid login configuration. Please make sure the
> `LoginConfiguration` provided is non-nil}

while running this:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(permissions: ["email, public_profile"], from: self) { (loginResult, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        
        if let currentToken = AccessToken.current {
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: currentToken.tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    let authError = error as NSError
                    print(authError)
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.setupTabbar()
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I checked info.plist several times and apply the instructions from scratch but I am still getting this error.

I am using XCode 12.5 and Swift 5

Edit: When I remove the permissions it works but I actually need those permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FBSDKLog: Cannot login without a valid login configuration. Please make sure the \`LoginConfiguration\` provided is non-nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723076/fbsdklog-cannot-login-without-a-valid-login-configuration-please-make-sure-the)

Comment: @ElTomato No, it doesn't. I already tried that, but thanks a lot.

Comment: If you’ve found a solution, you should add it as an answer, not as an update to the original question, so that it can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @ElTomato it actually helped me after all. However, I am still thinking about how it was working a while ago. I guess something is changed about Facebook login ios SDK while I am not actively developing this app. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Solution**

I changed permissions from `["email, public_profile"]` to:
`["email", "public_profile"]`

so it looks like this:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(permissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (loginResult, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        
        if let currentToken = AccessToken.current {
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: currentToken.tokenString)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.setupTabbar()
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```